# Match "any string" in Haskell record in HSpec test

Tags: haskell, hspec

I have a data class `Entity` which is defined like this:

```
data Entity = Entity { id :: String, name :: String }
```

and a function that returns `IO Entity`:

```
newPersistentEntity :: String -> IO Entity
```

And I'd like to write an [HSpec](https://hspec.github.io/) test for this:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = describe "newPersistentEntity function" $
       it "returns a new Entity with a generated id and the specified name" $
       newPersistentEntity "myName" `shouldReturn` Entity {id = <any string>, name = "myName"}
```

The problem is that the id is a UUID generated by the database. I want to assert that the `id` is a string to make the test pass.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create the record, then use its `id` value to create the record you're comparing against? Something like:

```
new <- newPersistentEntity "myName"
new `shouldBe` Entity { id = (id new), name = "myName" }
```

(Note: don't have enough information to test this code, treat this as somewhat pseudo code).

As a side note, your code doesn't look like normal Persistent code, so I'm assuming you're using a different library.

Comment: This is a good idea but databases like MongoDB generates  an id by default and it's not something that you necessarily    supply to the db. So is not exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Johan I'm suggesting you create the entity using e.g. MongoDB, then use any database-populated fields it returns to you to create a record which you then do comparisons with.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` of an `Entity` can't not be a `String`, because static typing. But you probably do want to force its evaluation to ensure that it isn't bottom.

```
spec :: Spec
spec = describe "newPersistentEntity function" $
    it "returns a new Entity with a generated id and the specified name" $ do
        x <- newPersistentEntity "myName"
        pure $! id x  -- Force evaluation of the `id` field to ensure that
                      -- the database actually did return a string here
        name x `shouldBe` "myName"
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved this myself in a different way that I'll show here for context. You probably shouldn't use it since the accepted answer is easier to understand and less verbose.

```
spec :: Spec
spec = describe "newPersistentEntity function" $
       it "returns a new Entity with a generated id and the specified name" $
       newPersistentEntity "myName" >>= (`shouldSatisfy` (\case
           Entity {id = _, name = "myName"} -> True
           _ -> False))
```

But for this to work you also need to apply the lamda case language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
```