# Simplify incomplete assertions in HSpec

Tags: haskell, hspec

I want to unit-test a function that returns a complex nested data structure, but I'm only interested in certain fields of that structure. For example:

```hs
expectedResult = Right (
  UserRecord {
    name = "someName",
    id = <don't care>
    address = AddressRecord {
      street = "someStreet",
      id = <don't care> 
      }
    }
  )
```

Is there a generic way to assert a result of the above form in HSpec? That is, some way to write an expression

```
result `shouldBe` expectedResult
```

where I do not need to specify those parts of the expected result that I am not interested in? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47681049/4090111) answer, which requires to copy over all *don't care* fields from `result` to `expectedResult`; this might get rather tedious. Maybe there is a standard approach using lenses? Or some library with assertion helpers I haven't heard of?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that you 'don't care' about the `id` fields? I'm asking because this is typical test smell I often encounter in general (i.e. in OOP contexts as well). IDs are often generated by a database, which make them non-deterministic and thus more difficult to test. Database-generated IDs in general has other architectural downsides, so if this is the case, it may be worthwhile to consider a better (and more functional) design.

Comment: In mz particular case at hand, it's not about the ID field in particular (I would use UUIDs if the DBMS permits). I'm trying to test a Servant server, where HTTP responses have all sorts of automatically fields I don't care about in the test (host name, server name and version, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach:

```hs
result `shouldSatisfy` \a ->
    name a == "someName"  &&
    street (address a) == "someStreet"
```